# Systemd executable failed to read file from CacheDirectory with Permission Denied

Tags: linux, systemd, permissions, systemd-timer, systemd-unit

I have a Golang binary that runs every 5 mins. It is supposed to create & update a text file which needs to be write restricted. To run this binary I created a systemd service and a systemd timer unit. Systemd service uses a DynamicUser. To achieve access restriction i use `CacheDirectory` directive in systemd so that only DynamicUser can write that file and it only exists as long as user exists. Also set `CacheDirectoryMode=644` to allow only owner with write permissions.

When systemd service runs, it is failing with
`failed to read output file: lstat /var/cache/monitor/output_file.txt: permission denied>`

**Question:** Although service unit will create a dynamic user & run an executable that creates/updates/reads the file, why that executable itself get Permission Denied when trying to read the file when systemd service runs?

file-monitor.go compiled to produce /usr/local/bin/file-monitor binary

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

function foo() {
    var outputFile = os.Getenv("CACHE_DIRECTORY") + "/output_file.txt"
    
    outputFileBytes, err := os.ReadFile(outputFile)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to read output file %s: %v\n", outputFile, err)
    }
}

function main() {
    foo()
}
```

file-updater.service

```
[Unit]
Description="description"
After=file-updater.service

[Service]
DynamicUser=yes
User=monitor
Group=monitor

CacheDirectory=monitor
CacheDirectoryMode=644

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/file-monitor <arg1>

Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CacheDirectoryMode=644
> ```

This allows to read the directory list. Not to interact with a file within this directory list: the eXecute bit is required to further traverse the path and access files within the directory. This makes the write access for user *monitor* also useless.

Change this parameter into:

```
CacheDirectoryMode=755
```

which is the default (ie: you can remove this parameter instead). This now allows to access files within this directory, for reading or for writing for user *monitor*.

The behavior is linked from *systemd*'s documentation ( [RuntimeDirectoryMode=, StateDirectoryMode=, CacheDirectoryMode=, LogsDirectoryMode=, ConfigurationDirectoryMode=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#RuntimeDirectoryMode=) ) to the manual for [`path_resolution(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) which include all the details about basic Unix access, especially in **Step 2: walk along the path** and in the **Permission** paragraphs:

> **If the process does not have search permission on the current lookup
> directory**, an EACCES error is returned ("Permission  denied").

> **Of the three bits used**, the first bit determines read permission, the
> second write permission, and **the last** execute permission in case of
> ordinary files, or **search permission in case of directories**.

Comment: I'm not sure if directory is owned by `User=monitor` or by the `DynamicUser`.  These aren't the same.  Regardless of that, you're right about the 755.

Comment: @Stewart https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#DynamicUser= . It appears that the user is really dynamic and transcient. I didn't know this was possible before this. I understand that means the user monitor will have a different uid on each run.

Comment: indeed that was the problem. Changing to 744 and it worked. @A.B follow up - I want to provide read access to this output file created by monitor user to another (static) user/group that already exists on the host. I tried adding `SupplementaryGroups=<OtherGroup>` to unit file, but that group user still can't read the file. Is it just not possible for non-Dynamic users to get any access to this path?

Comment: @Korba my answer says use 755, not 744. Try again.

Comment: For restriction, I guess you need a static group not named monitor to be provided as group. Forget about supplementarygroups. Anyway have it first working before trying again restrictions.

Comment: changed to 755 and see the CacheDirectory being created

```bash
[ ~ ]$ sudo getfacl /var/cache/monitor
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/cache/monitor
# owner: 62090
# group: 62090
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Comment: When you use `DynamicUser=`, `CacheDirectory=` may not be `/var/cache/monitor/`.  Each `DynamicUser=` gets a virtual filesystem where `/var/lib/private` and a symbolic link to a private mount which is cleaned after the service stops.